# how to retrieve node from xml file (tree strucuture) using php

Tags: php, xml, dom, xmldom

I have the following XML tree:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
    <start_info>
            <info tabindex="1">
            <infonumber>1</infonumber>
            <trees>green</trees>
            </info>
    </start_info>
    <people>
        <pe>
            <people_ages>
                <range number="1">
                    <age value="1">1</age>
                    <age value="2">2</age>
                </range>
            </people_ages>
        </pe>
    </people>
</root>
```

Firstly I have to display all of the nodes in the checkbox and then their node value have to retrieve on submit of the file.
I have to do it using PHP.

Comment: Can you please describe what you need more detailed, bec. it is not very clear what you need to do. And if you already have some code it would be nice to post it, so we can help you more effective.

Comment: hi paul! thnx for reply!! actually i have to parse a file in xml using php. the file consist on tree structure. and i have to bring all of the tag using checkboxes. for this i made lot of struggle but all in VAN...:(

Answer (score 1):

You can either you use

1)
    $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

```
echo $movies->movie[0]->plot;
OR
echo $movies->movie->{'great-lines'}->line;
```

2) good way and easy to use XML into Array,http://www.bin-co.com/php/scripts/xml2array/ this website gives you lib to convert XML to array.